# closed form solution to a recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have come up with this recurrence relation in solving a problem : 
$$
  \begin{cases}
    y_i = \lambda\{\sum_{m=1}^M (y_{i-1}^m)P_m + y_{i-1}P_0\}   & \quad  i\ge1 \\
    y_0 = 1\\
  \end{cases}
\
$$
which $P_m$ is described as $P_m = \binom{M}{m}p^m(1-p)^{M-m}$ (Binomial Distribution); $M$ is an integer $(M\ge1)$ and p and $\lambda$ are both real numbers between $0$ and $1$: $0\le p\le1$ , $0\le \lambda\le1$.

I want to know if it can have a closed form solution or if not, find some upper bounds for $\sum_{i=0}^\infty y_i$. Does anybody know about this recurrence relation or a similar one which can possibly help me in this problem?

Comment: For every $M$, $y_i=\Theta(\mu_M^i)$ where $\mu_M=\lambda(1+(M-1)p)(1-p)^{M-1}<1$. Is this the kind of estimate you are after?